# Django Auth LDAP - NO_SUCH_OBJECT

Tags: django, python-2.7, ldap, python-ldap, django-auth-ldap

Today out of the blue my WEBApp started failing in the login. I am authenticating the users against LDAP. The Web App is hosted on a Windows 2003 Server with Django 1.6.1 and Apache 2.2 and mod_wsgi.

The error is

> ERROR : 18/02/2015 01:52:17 PM : result(3) raised
>   NO_SUCH_OBJECT({'info': "0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001CD, problem
>   2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match
>   of:\n\t'OU=EU,DC=osud,DC=corp'\n", 'matched':
>   'OU=EU,DC=cosud,DC=corp', 'desc': 'No such object'},)

I checked on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5618-10/netscape/ldap/LDAPException.html#NO_SUCH_OBJECT and it says this

```
NO_SUCH_OBJECT

public static final int NO_SUCH_OBJECT
(32) The entry specified in the request does not exist.
```

At http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html it says this

```
exception ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT
The specified object does not exist in the directory. Sets the matched field of the exception dictionary value.
```

But none of these realy apply in the situation. And after like 2 hours the login started working again. There was a restart of Apache Server in between but not sure if that can contribute to this.

What else can i do to get to the bottom of this issue? Any more logging that can be added to get more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was related to my base DN: `OU=name,dc=some,dc=random,dc=organization`

The **CN** of my **OU** got changed and my python script started to show the same error message:

```
ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT: {'info': "0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001CD, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:\n\t'DC=some,DC=random,DC=organization'\n", 'matched': 'DC=some,DC=random,DC=organization', 'desc': 'No such object'}
```

Try running the query using some LDAP client (ldapsearch and Apache Directory Studio are my favorites) and compare the results.

I hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks Alfredo. It turned out that the AD was undergoing some maintenance leaving me bamboozled.